# What is the svchost.exe process and what does it do?

Tags: windows-7, malware, malware-removal, svchost

I often see `svchost.exe` processes in my task manager lately, and sometimes they seems to slow down my PC or get hanged. I have installed SVC host viewer, SVC Host process analyzer and Process Explorer. What should I do now?

I have the Avira antivirus installed on my PC and it doesn't help. sometimes when I open task manager, I see a `COM Surrogate` process which appears for around 1 second and then dissappears.

Also when I start my PC in the morning, on my screen it shows "`A disk error occurred,press Ctrl+Alt+Del to reboot`". Is this caused by `svchost.exe`, should I remove it?

Comment: sVChost or sCVhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[svchost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svchost) and [COM surrogate](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/2009/02/12) are both necessary for the functioning of Windows. It sounds like you've got a dying hard disk so now would be a good time to back everything up that's important!

If you think you've got a virus then have a look at [Microsoft Security Essentials](https://web.archive.org/web/20111026114126/http://www.microsoft.com:80/en-gb/security_essentials/default.aspx) as it picks up most things and is one most people have heard of.

You should be able to find more information out of the Event Log about whether it's a hardware or a software issue. See what kind of errors you've got in the "System" log (Event Viewer can be found under Control Panel --> Administrative Tools).